# Ubuntu 14.04 install nVIDIA Driver 3.52 Reboot and Black Screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, cuda

My notebook is ACER V3-571G , and GPU is GT 630M.
I replace DVD with SSD , and install Ubuntu 14.04.
However , I have some problem.
After installing nVIDIA Driver 352 ( for CUDA 7.5 and Theano ) , I reboot my notebook and screen is blank and black , no response.
How to solve my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me multiple times in 14.04 and again in 16.04. Every time you take an Nvidia driver update it seems I run the risk of getting a blank screen on reboot.

Here is how I have fixed it each time.
Purge all Nvidia-related packages

Boot int blank screen.

Log in to a terminal: Ctrl+Alt+F1 (terminal should still be accessible)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* libcuda-*
```

Rebooting should then get you to be able to log on using GUI.
Then the choice is yours. Try re-installing the propriety Nvidia drivers (sometimes it has worked for me - some times not) or try the Nouveau drivers that come with Ubuntu.

Sometimes taking a lesser version of the official drivers has also worked. Then I updated to a newer version a few months later and all was good.

I use Ubuntu for my work laptop so never take the driver updates when offered as a software update unless its the weekend or not a critical time as I have to be ready to spend time fixing and cleaning up when things go wrong which is about 50% of the time :)

Comment: I have investigeated that the driver 352 supports GT 630M.

Comment: Yeah - I hear you. The first time it happened to me I confirmed my card was listed as supported but every time I installed I got the blank screen. I ended up just using the Nouveau drivers at first.  My Dell 7759 with GeForce GTX 960M gave me the most problems with Nvidia drivers. We purchased 3 and my other 2 colleagues use Windows.  I watched them getting blue screens of death with official Nvidia supported drivers and having driver updates pushed daily via windows updates to fix issues but had to wait a few moths longer for a new Linux driver to come along before it became stable.